# Getting my function to work with appened elements Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a set of input boxes and you can add more and more sets of these forms if you click the add more button. In my form I can submit data and I have got it to show up when you reload the page. I have managed to get it alert something if the select box has a value of 0. However this is not working with my appended select boxes.

The jquery I am using to alert is this:

```
function valid() {
        if($j("select option:selected").val() == 0) {

            alert("Nothing is Selected");

        } if($j("select option:selected").val() != 0) {

            alert("Everything Is Selected");
        }
    }

$j("#submit-form").click(function(event){
        valid();
        /* Stops The Button From Submitting */

        event.preventDefault();

        /* Doing Ajax Stuff */
});
```

When I append another select box to my form this doesn't take into account the newly added select boxes. How can I get this to take into account all the select pages on the page?. I have tried putting my function in a document ready function or when I append the select boxes but this still doesn't work.

Here is my jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/benEdpa/0sLad9t5/19/

Comment: What you have should work, assuming the `select` elements are correctly added to the DOM before the click event is raised. Can you add a working example showing the problem in a http://jsfiddle.net. As an aside, if you're submitting a form, you should hook to the `submit` event of the form, not the click of a button.

Comment: Hello, here is my js fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/benEdpa/0sLad9t5/19/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [.each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/) in demo use .class to [.each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/)

```js
 
$('#is-add').on('click',function(){
  var opt = [
    '<option value="0">0</option>',
    '<option value="1">1</option>',
    ].join('');
    
  $('#in-box').append($('<select>',{'class':'sel-class'}).append(opt));
    
});
    
$('#is-submit').on('click',function(){
    var sel_val = []
    $('.sel-class').each(function(){
        sel_val.push($(this).val());
    });

    if(sel_val.indexOf('0') === -1){
      $('h1').html('true go next process');
      return true;
    }else{
      $('h1').html('false select value = "0"');
      return false;
    }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="in-box">
  <select class="sel-class">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
   </select>
  </div><br/>
<a href="#" id="is-add">add</a><br/>
<a href="#" id="is-submit">valid test</a>
<h1></h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Demo</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function valid() {
            if ($("select option:selected").val() == "0") {
                alert("Nothing is Selected");
            } if ($("select option:selected").val() != "0") {
                alert("Everything Is Selected");
            }
        }
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var str = "<select>";
            str += "<option value=\"0\">ALL</option>";
            str += "<option value=\"1\">1</option>  ";
            str += "<option value=\"2\">2</option>  ";
            str += "</select>";
            $('#ddlappend').append(str);
            $("#submit").click(function (event) {
                valid();
                /* Stops The Button From Submitting */
                event.preventDefault();
                /* Doing Ajax Stuff */
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div id="ddlappend"></div>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello! This doesn't work. I have tried adding my append to the document ready and it still doesn't work

Comment: Whats Error Coming??

Comment: I am not getting an error I am still getting the same problem where the function is not working with the appended forms.